# Android: что такое статический context?

Tags: java, android

Пишу код придложения под Android для работы с БД `SQLite`. Неоднократно сталкиваюсь с предупреждением об ошибке

> Non-static method 'method()' cannot be referenced from a static
>   context

Во-первых: какой такой `static context`? В моём коде (пока что) ни одного статического метода, ни одной статической переменной, разве что одна статическая константа одна есть для ведения лога.

Вот пару примеров, где такое предупреждение появляется:

●　Метод `addNewItem` для добавления новой записи в БД (принадлежит отдельному классу для работы с БД):

```
public TestDB(Context context) {
   this.context = context;
   dbHelper = new testDBHelper (context);
}

public void addNewItem(String title, String noteText){
   db = testDBHelper .getWritableDatabase(context); // здесь
   ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

   cv.put(testDBHelper .KEY_TITLE, title);
   cv.put(testDBHelper .KEY_TEXT, noteText);
   cv.put(testDBHelper .KEY_DATE, new Date().getTime());

   db.insert(testDBHelper .TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}
```

●　Сохранение в БД введённых в поля значений (код принадлежит Activity с полями ввода):

```
String title = editTitle.getText().toString();
String text = editText.getText().toString();

TestDB testDB = new TestDB(AddItemActivity.getApplicationContext()); // здесь
testDB.addNewItem(title, note);
```

Признаю, что на данный момент я почти без понимания работаю с `context`, потому буду благодарен за любые объяснения.

Конструктор

```
public TestDB(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    testDBHelper = new TestDBHelper(context);
}
```

в классе для работы с БД имеется; в Activity c полями ввода - нет.

Comment: В данном случае ошибка не имеет ничего общего с классом `Context` - там сказано, что нестатические методы не могут ссылаться на статическое окружение.  Метод `getWritableDatabase()` не принимает [никаких параметров](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase()) - `getWritableDatabase()` вместо `getWritableDatabase(context)`

Comment: getWritableDatabase() - метод класса SQLiteOpenHelper (), наследником которого является TestDBHelper.

Comment: Вот [код](http://androiddocs.ru/rabota-s-bazoj-dannyx-sqllite/), который я взял за основу. Тут нет аргумента. Понимаю, что я не должен тупо повторять за автором кода, но пока не хватает понимания. Метод `addNewItem()` добавил я.

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что  методу `getWritableDatabase()` нужно передавать экземпляр класса `Context` ?

Comment: Так, прочитав Ваш вопрос, разобрался. В первом случае контекст дейтсвительно не нужен. Когда по ошибке обращался к классу, то слово `context` в предупреждении ввело в заблуждение. Во втором случае неправильное обращение к контексту; правильное будет `AddItemActivity.this`. Напишите тогда, пожалуйста в ответе какой-нибудь теоретической комментарий о static context, чтобы я поставил Вам галочку и этот вопрос можно было закрыть.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае вы столкнулись с ошибкой компиляции при попытке вызова **нестатического** метода `getApplicationContext()` класса `AddItemActivity` способом вызова статических методов

Т.е. если бы метод был объявлен статическим то ошибки бы не было.

В вашем случае вам надо вызвать нестатический метод через ссылку на класс, не через его имя, как это делается для статических методов. Ссылку на класс можно получить через `this` или `AddItemActivity.this`. Тогда вызов метода будет выглядеть так:

```
AddItemActivity.this.getApplicationContext()
```