# non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context java

Tags: java, android

Делаю WebView приложение. Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы кнопка "назад" не закрывала приложение, а возвращала на предыдущую страницу. Но на методах canGoBack() и goBack() появляется ошибка "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context java". Как это исправить?

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (WebView.canGoBack()) {
            WebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Android: что такое статический context?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600940/android-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-context)

Answer (score 1):

Вы вызываете нестатический метод как статический (через имя класса), тогда как надо вызывать метод на переменной, которая является ссылкой на WebView в разметке.

Если на уровне класса у вас нет переменной типа `WebView webView`, на которой можно вызвать  ваши методы `webView.canGoBack()`, `webView.goBack()`, то создайте эту переменную и/или создайте её прямо в `onBackPressed` методе, хотя это и вызовет небольшую просадку производитеьности.